# Double right arrow when typesetting Scala sources in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, arrows

How do you produce the unicode double right arrow variant of function types when typesetting Scala code with LaTeX? I can use math escape, like so

```
\lstset{mathescape=true}
\begin{lstlisting}
val x = (i: Int) $\Rightarrow$ i*i
\end{lstlisting}
```

But that breaks the monospacing. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but at tex... nobody knows Scala. I suspect much more people here who occasionally publish papers and are thus confronted with this question.

Comment: I can't find anything giving you those arrows in text mode. What you could do to maintain spacing, however, is put the whole line in math mode and put everything but the \rightarrow in \text{}, like so: `$\text{val x = (i: Int) } \Rightarrow \text{i*i}$`

Comment: @Werner Yes, I moved the question there, although it is slightly different. I have to evaluate the one answer there, and will close this question if it is solved.

Comment: What's the purpose of asking the question on [so]? The only effect has been migration and the question has already appeared on this site, although in slight different form.

Comment: @egreg I suspected people who program Scala and publish papers are confronted with this question, and that they read SO and not tex.stackexchange.com. The question was also slightly different, I was asking _what_ people do to typeset the right arrow, whereas my tex question was how to deal with the spacing.